# How to update the contents of page at the same time using ajax?

Tags: ajax

example: There are two tabs in browser which are displaying the same page.. now the problem is when i update the content of first tab using ajax the result will only be visible in the next tab after reloading the page..

How to make it work without manually refreshing the page?

Comment: I have just tried simple ajax code which retrieves the information from server and updated the content..

Comment: You can see websockets, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for that. There is a websocket implementation for node.js javascript called [Socket.io](http://socket.io/). By using this, instead of pulling data from server, you can notify all the client connected to your server. Here is a simple implementation:

**Client:**

```
<script src="path_to/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://your_rest_server');
  socket.on('update', function (response) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHtml = response.data;
  });
</script>
```

**Server:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('update', { data: 'New content' });
});
```

In above script, server sends update to all clients to connected in a box called "update". Servers already listens box called "update". When any new content has arrived, it put data to specified html area

You can see more detail [here](http://socket.io/#home)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.. :)